# Git error: Unable to create file in VS code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

For the first time when I clone my project repo and make deployment through VS code, the PR which I create gets deployed properly and everything works fine. But when I try to open VS code on next day, and want to create another PR on same repo, I get to see some files in changes section on the left which someone else has made. So I tried to take latest pull and discard those files but I get an error- "Git:Unable to create file." Even when I tried to stash, the files are not getting eliminated. Because of this neither am I able to create task branch nor am I able to work on the master branch and create PR for deployment.

I have also tried certain git commands to discard files present in chnages section that are displaying... but nothing worked. Please help.

Comment: Copy and paste the exact commands and output, or (as a last resort) show a screenshot (don't do that if text will suffice). See [ask]. Provide the exact sequence of commands that reproduces the error (see [mre]).

Comment: @torek may be now you can understand, please reread my now edited question